# Why does Anakin/Luke's Lightsaber change colour?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-wars

In ***Star Wars- Episode IV- A New Hope*** Luke's lightsaber has a light blue color, almost white, however in the prequel films the same blade is a dark blue instead.

Here's the blade in *A New Hope*:

[image]

and here it is in *Revenge of the Sith*

[image]

Is there an in universe reason for this change in color or is it simply a byproduct of the newer out-of-universe production techniques of making the lightsabers?

Update: The same lightsaber is once again deep blue in *The Force Awakens*:

[image][image]

Comment: Seriously, I cannot make out any differences in those lightsabers, blue is blue. The explanation that the technique for making those effects changed is probably the most likely (though, good will keeps me from downvoting for now).

Comment: Really - that surprises me, I've always seen them as very different blues!  But then I like blue! :-)

Comment: As a side note, colors on an object can change based on the lighting in a room.  Colors _from_ a light source are subject to the same effects.  Additionally, one presumes that the color of the plasma would be effected by the temperature of the blade and the atmosphere in the room - different gases have different [spectrums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectroscopy).  Given that it also lists crystals on that page.... perhaps, in universe, it could just be the age of the saber?  Out of universe, it probably is just the technique...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse personally I think it's that GL changed his mind - most of the sabers in the early films are this sea blue.  In the later films they've all become much more uniform.

Comment: Close Vote - There is no major difference in lightsabers.

Comment: Anakin's lightsaber has been sitting in Ben's dusty hope chest for 20+ years. Its battery is a bit flat.

Comment: This might help, I asked a similiar question over at scifi.se.
[Why were some lightsaber effects in A New Hope different quality?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11094/why-were-some-lightsaber-effects-in-a-new-hope-different-quality)

Comment: The close votes seem to indicate that most people don't see a  major differences

Comment: I still wouldn't propose to close it, though. However ridiculous the question may be, it still seems valid to me.

Comment: Related: http://www.dvdactive.com/editorial/articles/star-wars-the-changes-part-one.html Luke, Vader, and Ben's lightsabers all change color between releases, and often just white.

Comment: Preface note: I have given this issue a lot of thought. I have intentionally searched the web for fan discussion of this color difference, and I'm glad the question was asked. I felt it important to note that I, too, see a massive color difference in the prequels relative to the original films. The color change is far too dramatic and appears too deliberate to be chalked up to issues of pre-release formatting. The color of Anakin's/Luke's lightsaber in 'Star Wars' (1977) was always notably light though obviously inconsistent, both among differing releases and within the film itself: in every V

Comment: I can't see what all the fuss is about Luke's saber or Anakin's saber as given to him by Obi Wan was yellow. The proof is in the action figures released.
Even now with all the messing around and ruining a perfectly ok movie the action figure still sports a YELLOW lightsaber. Thank god I have the proper version on tape.

Comment: While you are clearly looking at "out of universe" technological differences, because this is meant to be the same lightsaber with the same kyber crystal, there R technological differences between films and/or differences in artist choices (a scene's lighting), I do want to point out that there can be great and subtle differences in blade colors depending on the [kyber] crystal used, the mechanics of any given lightsaber design (Kylo Ren's ancient design is unstable due to both the design & a "cracked" crystal), and/or manipulation of said crystals (red color = bleeding the crystal)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As @Jared points out in the comments, differences in the color of lightsabers between the Star Wars episodes, can be attributed to post-production.  There is no canonical (in-universe) reason for these color differences.

For example, and taken directly from the [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11094/why-were-some-lightsaber-effects-in-a-new-hope-different-quality) that Jared linked to...
[image: It's Green] 
...before the last edited release on Blu-ray in 2011, it was made green (on the 2004 DVD edition). More than likely, if you are watching a copy of Star Wars that was released before 2004, you will find color differences from scene to scene. The 1997 Special Edition and original version, the same lightsaber in this scene is white.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the filmmakers have a "better technology" to make a "better" more intense blue, then that is exactly when the saber changes color.

Yes, I've noticed this and yes it has bothered me as well.  Just makes for more inconsistencies within StarWars.

It isn't the only change made to lightsabers.  Initially George Lucas wanted them to appear heavy, hence a wielder needing both hands to control it.  Unfortunately though, for this effect, the lightsaber props must not have actually been heavy since the direction to actors was that they should "Act As If" they're heavy.  Well, only a mime could pull off that kind of acting.

After a while, this also changed to become acrobatic gnomes twirling lazersticks.  But I wish it hadn't, I rather like the idea that in its OFF position (the configuration resembling a flashlight without batteries) a lightsaber hilt is lightweight and can freely dangle from your belt without depantsing your desert-khakis.  However if it were to POWER ON then it becomes heavy, so if you had not yet unhooked it from your carabiner clip, then let's just hope you're also wearing your Jedi robe for quick cover-up.

I wish this model was not abandoned, a heavy lightsaber implies that its plasma blade is not merely "a lightbeam" but something which can carve into a steel spaceship door.  If they'd kept the heavy model, then 1977's duel between Old Ben and Master of Evil "Darth" would not have aged so terribly, becoming slow and antiquated.

Sidenote: I wonder if the filmmakers were aiming to get back to basics while making The Force Awakens, since those duels resembled those of the original trilogy.

Comment: Welcome to Movies.SE! This answer would be better if you removed the long, borderline rant about lightsaber weights, because it's irrelevant to the question.